# Is the java process terminated when his streams (Error and Input Stream) are terminated?

Tags: java, process, inputstream, runtime.exec, terminate

I know that the process will be blocked if its error and input streams are not completely read.

- Does this mean that the process is finished (all his commands were executed) when its streams have been completely read (no data in the stream, the end of the stream has been reached)?
- Is it possible that the streams are terminated but the process not?
- How can I be sure that the process is complete?

  I could not find information about this in the documentation.

Another Question:
As mentioned below, it is possible that the streams are terminated but the process not. In this case: could these kinds of processes contain any commands or actions to do or are they only processes without actions or anything to do? And the second question:  how can i terminate a process after a certain timeout although Process.waitFor() is used?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process.waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) method to wait until process completion

Comment: thank you, but can you tell me if the process is still alive if his streams are terminated (no more data comes from the stream)?

Comment: No, process can be still in this case

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that the process is finished (all his commands were executed) when its streams have been completely read (no data in the stream, the end of the stream has been reached)?

No, it does not. Conversely:

> is it possible that the streams are terminated but the process not?

Yes, this is perfectly possible.

> How can I be sure that the process is complete? I could not find information about this in the documentation.

Using `Process.waitFor()`.

Comment: thank you. so i have another two question. As you say it is possible that the streams are terminated but the process not. In this case: could this process contain any commands or actions to do or is it only a process without actions or anything to do? And the second question:  how can i terminate a process after a certain timeout even though he is not finished

Comment: @user1855808 regarding the first question, yes, the process can do any action other than perform output to its standard output streams. Regarding the second, I think you should search StackOverflow to look for answers, or pose another question if you can't find any.